# problem creating odd and even cell in a table in Vue Js

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, vue.js, v-for

Here is my code, myData is my vue data model which has some field: a,b, ...
odd-cell and even-cell are the CSS classes with different background color. its a foreach loop, how can i calcultate something like if (length of myData % 2 == 1)  in v-if  to add the odd and even class in my div.

```
            <div v-for="item in myData">
                <div v-if="" class='odd-cell'>
                    <p> {{item.a}} </p>
                    <p> {{item.b}} </p>
                </div>
                <div v-else class='even-cell'>
                   <p> {{item.a}} </p>
                   <p> {{item.b}} </p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

[i am writing in cshtml view page, so you can suggest c# code as well..]

Answer (score 6):

I refered to a UI framework which now I'm using, name as [iView](https://www.iviewui.com/components/table-en).

Of course, they also support striped table component. So I wondered how they do like that.

```
.ivu-table-stripe .ivu-table-body tr:nth-child(2n) td,
.ivu-table-stripe .ivu-table-fixed-body tr:nth-child(2n) td {
    background-color: #f8f8f9;
}
```

As you can see, CSS support for handling each case of even and odd by using `nth-child()`. There is no more simple way to do like that.

further more, you can use more complex formula as a parameter like this : 
`(an + b).`

[W3School Nth-child Example](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) maybe helpful for you.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `index`:

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in myData">
   <div v-if="" :class="{'odd-cell': index % 2 === 1, 'even-cell': index % 2 === 0}">
       <p> {{item.a}} </p>
       <p> {{item.b}} </p>
   </div>
</div>
```

But there are better solution with css `nth-child`

```
div:nth-child(odd) {
    background: red;
}

div:nth-child(even) {
    background: blue;
}
```